# $\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}}+\sin{\frac{B+C}{2}}+\sin{\frac{C+A}{2}} > \sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{C}. $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Help me please to prove that:

for any $\triangle ABC$ we have the following inequality: $$\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}}+\sin{\frac{B+C}{2}}+\sin{\frac{C+A}{2}} > \sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{C}. $$

It's about convexity ?

thanks :)

Comment: i might have a solution to this in my old notebook. i will find and post.

Comment: ok, please. Thanks :)

Comment: I think I have the solution. $\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}} > \frac{\sin{A}+\sin{B}}{2}$ and the analogues, so the inequality is proved. Is ok ?

Comment: yes, it seems correct to me.

Comment: Technically, you should have $\ge$.

Comment: @Iuli Why don't you post an answer seeing as you've solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin A+\sin B=\sin(\frac{A+B}{2}+\frac{A-B}{2})+\sin(\frac{A+B}{2}-\frac{A-B}{2})=2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}\leqslant2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}$. Similarly, $\sin B+\sin C\leqslant2\sin\frac{B+C}{2},\sin C+\sin A\leqslant2\sin\frac{A+C}{2}$. Add them together yields the result.

Note that the inequality holds is due to $\frac{A+B}{2}\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and similar for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Eliminate $\angle C$

$A+B+C=180^0 \implies C=180-(C+B)$

Now you just need to show :

$\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}}+\sin{(90-\dfrac{A}{2})}+\sin{(90-\dfrac{B}{2})} \ge \sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{(180-(A+B))}$

$\sin{\frac{A+B}{2}} +\cos{\frac{B}{2}}+\cos{\frac{A}{2}} \ge \sin A+ \sin B+ \sin(A+B)$